# SCP files to remote host in JAVA using JCraft's JSch API

Tags: upload, directory, scp, jsch

I am able to scp a single file to the remote machine on an existing folder using JSch API but not able to do so if the folder doesn't exists on remote.

On each run I would need to SCP files to unique folder that has name with date time format.

Since the folder does not exists in remote.. my SCP file transfer fails.. i was hoping that it would create the folder if it does not exists.

SCP to existing folder works but I would like to SCP file to a newly created folder using JSch API.

Help appreciated..!!

Answer (score 0):

I used JSch Channel SFtp to create the required directory on remote box & i was able to do that.. Now I have the directory available on remote server & I should be able to SCP file to that folder..